# Convexity conditions for an Infimum operation

Tags: convex-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, weighted-least-squares

I came across these 2 seemingly contradictory statements in the book 'Convex Optimization' by Boyd.

[image]

and

[image: m]

So the top image is said to be concave.
For the simplest case where $n=1$ the function is the same as described below as a convex function. So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top equation (with $n = 1$), the 'inner' function is
$$f(w,x) = w \, (a^\top x - b)^2.$$
This function is not convex. However, it is linear (thus concave) in the variable $w$. Thus,
$$g(w) = \inf_x f(w,x)$$
is the infimum of the family of convex functions $\{f(\cdot, x) \mid x\}$.

In the bottom equation, $f$ is assumed to be convex (i.e., convex in $(x,y)$). This results in $g$ being convex.

Comment: Assume the single dimensioal case. how is $(ax-b)^2$ not convex? I understand since the function is w.r.t $w$ the function is linear and taking infimum makes it a concave function, thus similarly taking supremum w,r,t $w$ should make it a convex function?

Comment: This function is convex, but you have the factor $w$ and $f(w,x) = w(ax-b)^2$ is not convex on $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Oh I see....just for clarification since the $g(w)$ is linear in $w$ does it mean if we used $sup$ it would result in a convex function?

Comment: Also how did you determine that the function was not convex in $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: Yes, the supremum would be convex. The non-convexity can be checked by e.g. the Hessian test.